# How to Refer to a count(*) column in a PDO Query

Tags: php, pdo

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT t.name, COUNT(*) 
                        FROM team t
                        JOIN member m ON FIND_IN_SET( m.team_id, t.id ) >0
                        GROUP BY t.name
                        LIMIT 0 , 30");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_BOUND);
$stmt->bindColumn('count', $count);
$stmt->bindColumn('name', $name);
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) 
{
     echo "<tr><td>".$name."</td>";                   
    echo "<td>".$count."</td>";
 }
```

The code above retrieves 2 columns: name and the `count(*)`. The problem is with accessing the count column; I get the below error.

> Warning: PDOStatement::bindColumn(): SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: Did not find column name 'count' in the defined columns; it will not be bound in

How can I bind to that total count?

Comment: I think aliasing would work, I haven't used the `bindcolumn` before though. `SELECT t.name as name, COUNT(*) as count`.

Comment: Aliasing is definitely the way to go, but also you can `var_dump($row);` and look at what the key is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an alias: `COUNT(*) as count`.

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT t.name, COUNT(*) as count
                        FROM team t
                        JOIN member m ON FIND_IN_SET( m.team_id, t.id ) >0
                        GROUP BY t.name
                        LIMIT 0 , 30");

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_BOUND);
$stmt->bindColumn('count', $count);
$stmt->bindColumn('name', $name);

while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) 
{
    echo "<tr><td>".$name."</td>";                   
    echo "<td>".$count."</td>";
}
```

Comment: @user580950 Glad to help! Please remember to accept the answer. By the way, in the future, please be sure to tag the database you're using (MySQL or whatever).

Comment: sure SF says wait for 10 minutes to accept the answer and I will

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using aliases with column names, you can specify the column number (starting from 1).

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT t.name, COUNT(*) 
                        FROM team t
                        JOIN member m ON FIND_IN_SET( m.team_id, t.id ) >0
                        GROUP BY t.name
                        LIMIT 0 , 30");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_BOUND);
$stmt->bindColumn(2, $count);
$stmt->bindColumn(1, $name);
```